# When cloning existing site locally I get the following error "...properties already exists in the selected store."

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml

When cloning a site for local development I get the following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:223:"Error in file: "/Applications/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/data/cms_setup/data-install-1.6.0.0.php" - A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store.";i:1;s:1100:"#0 /Applications/apache2/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
```

Im using a MAMP stack. The existing database was imported and connect via local.xml.

I cant edit core. Why is this error coming up? Conflict between wanting to setup new install vs using existing db?

Comment: Can you elaborate your process please? If you really imported the core DB, this script should never be executed, because the core_resource table should already have an entry for the CMS module in the required version.

Comment: In core resource there is an entry for 1.6.0.0.2 but the value in the error is 1.6.0.0.0.

Comment: Ok so you did download source -> import db -> connect db in local xml -> load page? Are you sure you downloaded the exact same version as before, including patches? Also, what happens if you simply change the entry in core_resource?

Comment: I put the sql file in mysql/bin and ran source DB_Name. When I deleted it I got a new error.

Comment: WHen I change the identifer where it says it already exists a new one is automatically created and the same error comes back.

Comment: This is a weird error. I would recommend to use `n98-magerun.phar db:dump` and `n98-magerun.phar db:import` for another clean backup to elminiate that it's the DB's fault. Do you have a table prefix set in the `local.xml` file?